# How to open Android SDK automatically after executing "ionic capacitor run android" in visual studio?

Tags: android, visual-studio, ionic-framework, capacitor

Is there something specific I need to set in my capacitor.config.ts file?  This is what it looks like at the moment:

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from '@capacitor/cli';
const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.project.project1',
  appName: 'project1-app',
  webDir: 'www',
  bundledWebRuntime: false
};
export default config;
```

Comment: `ionic capacitor build android` this command will copy all assets and open android studio.

Comment: Something to bear in mind - if you want to use the `--livereload` (or `-l`) option, it doesn't work with `ionic capacitor build android`.  Instead, you have to use `ionic capacitor run android -l --external`.  Some people have suggested using the `--host=[your IP address]`, but that isn't necessary when using the `--external` option, at least with API level 28.  That said, `ionic capacitor run android` won't automatically open your code in the Android SDK - you'll have to do that manually.  But if you don't plan to code in the Android SDK, that shouldn't cause you any inconvenience.